# Search for venues annotated by brand

Tags: foursquare

I'm specifically looking to find venues which a NY Times has annotated data for.  The goal is to call `/venues/VENUE_ID/annotations` and get links to articles referring to that venue.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search.html

The above api documentation is clear that `providerId` and `linkedId` must be used in conjunction with one another but `linkedId` seems proprietary and secret to the annotator (the NY Times).

Is there any way to just search by `providerId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no way to filter search by providerId.

The linkedId for a provider is the internal ID they use for referencing the venue. In the case of the NYTs, they put this ID in the URL of their Restaurant Details page (e.g. http://www.nytimes.com/restaurants/1247467962332/abc-kitchen/details.html)

[/venues/link](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/links.html) returns all annotations for a venueId.

Comment: do you know what the providerId is for instagram?